# Explicit boolean conversion

Tags: javascript

I have a variable which is either set to something or is undefined. I wish to pass to a function `true` if the variable is defined else `false`. Here is the function:

```
function f(areRowsSelectable){...}
```

Which of the following would you do?

```
f(v);


f(v?true:false);
```

Or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use double negation (which means applying the [logical NOT operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) twice) for explicit boolean conversion:

```
!!v
```

Examples:

```
!!'test' // true
!!'' // false
!!0 // false
!!1 // true
!!null // false
!!undefined // false
!!NaN // false
```

Alternatively, also `Boolean(v)` would work.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the "typeOf" guard method.

It does not accept "truthy" arguments, so it depends on your function whether you can use it.

The `tests` are basically the same as [czosel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585647/explicit-boolean-conversion#40585668)'s answer, but his answer returns "truthy" while mine only accepts `boolean true` as `true`.

```js
var tests = [
  //filled string
  'test',
  //empty string
  '',
  //Numeric empty
  0,
  //Numeric filled
  1,
  //Null
  null,
  //Completely undefined
  ,
  //undefined
  undefined,
  //Not-A-Number numeric value
  NaN,
  //Boolean true
  true
];
for (var t = 0; t < tests.length; t++) {
  var test = tests[t];
  var results = {
    test: test,
    isTruthy: !!test,
    isBoolTrue: (typeof test != "boolean" ? false : test),
    isDefined: (test !== void 0)
  };
  console.log(results);
}
```

**EDIT 1**

Since the question could be interpreted in several ways, i have included a couple of more tests.

1. `isTruthy` matches [czosel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585647/explicit-boolean-conversion#40585668)'s answer. Registers `truthy` values like `1` as `true`.
2. `isBoolTrue` was my first interpretation where it checks strictly whether a value is `boolean true`.
3. `isDefined` simply returns if the variable contains anything at all.

Comment: "I wish to pass to a function true if the variable is defined else false" -> I think the OP actually asks for "truthy-conversion".